# Power BI Count number of repeating ID

Tags: powerbi

How do I count repeating ID? I want to put it on the new column, it really doesn't matter if the number of total is repeating example like (if out come is this then better):

```
==========|=
   10327  |2
   10327  |2
   10328  |3
   10328  |3
   10328  |3
```

[image: RepeatingID]

Answer (score 6):

Use a calculated column like this:

```
NrOfOccurrences = CALCULATE(
    COUNT([OrderID]); 
    FILTER(Orders; [OrderID] = EARLIER('Orders'[OrderID])))
```

From bottom to top:

- `FILTER` gives you a table per row that has all rows with the same `OrderID`
- `COUNT` would count the number of `OrderID`s, effectively the number of rows
- `CALCULATE` puts them together, so that the number of rows in the relevant `FILTER` table is counted;

For example this is a screenshot of a manually entered table:

[image: example table]

Comment: Thank you for putting the definition making it more easier for me to understand it.

Comment: If I wanted to create a column of 1 NrOfoccurances per OrderID how do I do that ?

Comment: Errr... right click the dataset, add column with formula `NrOfOcc = 1`? If you're having trouble with that, best ask a new question (be sure the question lives up to the guidelines outlined in the [help])