# Duplicates in a month period

Tags: dax

I have a problem. I need to count duplicates for only a month at a time

[Power BI Count number of repeating ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629409/power-bi-count-number-of-repeating-id/42636143#42636143)

when I use the DAX formula above the column calculates all occurrences over my whole data set

```
NrOfOccurrences =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( [OrderID] );
    FILTER ( Orders; [OrderID] = EARLIER ( 'Orders'[OrderID] ) )
)
```

Table Results I get

```
Order ID Date   Occurrence 
3        Jan-18 7 
3        Jan-18 7 
3        Jan-18 7 
3        Feb-18 7 
3        Feb-18 7 
3        Feb-18 7 
3        Feb-18 7
```

Result I need

```
Order ID Date   Occurrence 
3        Jan-18 3 
3        Jan-18 3 
3        Jan-18 3 
3        Feb-18 4 
3        Feb-18 4 
3        Feb-18 4 
3        Feb-18 4
```

Please can Someone help?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, your DAX and expected outcome.

Comment: NrOfOccurrences = CALCULATE(
    COUNT([OrderID]); 
    FILTER(Orders; [OrderID] = EARLIER('Orders'[OrderID])))                                          Table Results I get   
Order ID  Date Occurrence
3 Jan-18 7
3 Jan-18 7
3 Jan-18 7
3 Feb-18 7
3 Feb-18 7
3 Feb-18 7
3 Feb-18 7
  
Result I need   
Order ID  Date Occurrence
3 Jan-18 3
3 Jan-18 3
3 Jan-18 3
3 Feb-18 4
3 Feb-18 4
3 Feb-18 4
3 Feb-18 4
@mxix

Comment: Include it in your question, you can Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `ALLEXCEPT` to specify which columns you want to keep when you transition row context to filter context.

```
NrOfOccurrences =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Orders'[OrderID] );
    ALLEXCEPT( Orders; 'Orders'[OrderID]; 'Orders'[Date] )
)
```

You could also add a condition to your `FILTER`.

```
NrOfOccurrences =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Orders'[OrderID] );
    FILTER (
        Orders;
        'Orders'[OrderID] = EARLIER ( 'Orders'[OrderID] ) &&
        'Orders'[Date] = EARLIER ( 'Orders'[Date] )
    )
)
```